# Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion'

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I got this message error in the way to open my report, any body has suggestion?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

i can't post an image couse i doesn't have any reputation

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the reference for CristalDescisions or you need an installation of it which works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Install Cristal reports
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193336
[image: Cristal reports]

Regards